# SonarQube - specify location of sonar.properties

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to deploy SonarQube on Kubernetes using configMaps.

The latest 7.1 [image](https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/) I use has a config in sonar.properties embedded in `$SONARQUBE_HOME/conf/` . The directory is not empty and contain also a wrapper.conf file.

I would like to mount the configMap inside my container in a other location than /opt/sonar/conf/ and specify to sonarQube the new path to read the properties.

Is there a way to do that ? (environment variable ? JVM argument ? ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to modify this standard configuration in any way. But we can have a look at the SonarQube sourcecode. In [this](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/e737a37b28a2504aa1a6387606841afd776f2fef/server/sonar-main/src/main/java/org/sonar/application/config/AppSettingsLoaderImpl.java) file you can find this code for reading the configuration file:

```
private static Properties loadPropertiesFile(File homeDir) {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    File propsFile = new File(homeDir, "conf/sonar.properties");
    if (propsFile.exists()) {
      ...
    } else {
      LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppSettingsLoaderImpl.class).warn("Configuration file not found: {}", propsFile);
    }
    return p;
}
```

So the conf-path and filename is hard coded and you get a warning if the file does not exist. The home directory is found this way:

```
private static File detectHomeDir() {
  try {
    File appJar = new File(Class.forName("org.sonar.application.App").getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
    return appJar.getParentFile().getParentFile();
  } catch (...) {
     ...
}
```

So this can also not be changed. The code above is used here:

```
@Override
public AppSettings load() {
    Properties p = loadPropertiesFile(homeDir);
    p.putAll(CommandLineParser.parseArguments(cliArguments));
    p.setProperty(PATH_HOME.getKey(), homeDir.getAbsolutePath());
    p = ConfigurationUtils.interpolateVariables(p, System.getenv());
    ....
}
```

This suggests that you can use commandline parameters or environment variables in order to change your settings.

Comment: I accept this answer, thx. Environment variable are useful but unfortunately, it's not possible to configure all sonarqube setting from sonar.properties with them.

Answer (score 0):

For my problem, I defined environment variable to configure database settings in my Kubernetes deployment :

```
      env:
      - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL
        value: jdbc:sqlserver://mydb:1433;databaseName=sonarqube
      - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME
        value: sonarqube
      - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: sonarsecret
            key: dbpassword
```

I needed to use also ldap plugin but it was not possible to configure environment variable in this case. As `/opt/sonarqube/conf/` is not empty, I can't use configMap to decouple configuration from image content. So, I build my own sonarqube image adding the ldap jar plugin and ldap setting in sonar.properties :

```
# General Configuration
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url=ldap://myldap:389
ldap.bindDn=CN=mysa=_ServicesAccounts,OU=Users,OU=SVC,DC=net
ldap.bindPassword=****

# User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=OU=Users,OU=SVC,DC=net
ldap.user.request=(&(sAMAccountName={0})(objectclass=user))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail

# Group Configuration
ldap.group.baseDn=OU=Users,OU=SVC,DC=net
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=group)(member={dn}))
```